# Как сделать двойной редирект?

Tags: javascript, html, редирект

Когда пользователь нажимает на ссылку его перенаправляет на другую страницу, а от туда по истечению 2 секунд еще на одну страницу. Возможно ли это сделать имея доступ только к первой странице с ссылкой? Спасибо

Comment: Нет, так сделать нельзя. Если в руках у вас под контролем первая страница - можете дать линк сразу на нужную страницу без промежуточных. Возможно, вам стоит объяснить, какую задачу вы хотите решить - и мы попробуем подсказать осуществимый вариант решения без этих множественных редиректов.

Comment: @AK, не, так сделать можно, просто более изощренным способом)

Comment: @AK, создать класс определение модулей страницы, если редирект был выполнен с той ссылки, то через пару сек. перенаправлять на другую страницу) Все просто

Comment: @AK, что значит "нет доступа", поясните, раз я не понял задачи

Comment: @meine Вы программист сайта, домашней странички site.ru, разместили ссылку на своей странице на яндекс:почту и хотите чтобы через две секунды после захода на сайт почты вас средиректило на гмейл. Нет доступа - это не ваш сайт. Не можете менять код страницы и рассчитывать что на этой странице будет какой-то код, который вы сможете менять. Я это так прочитал, а уж что думает топикстартер  - надо его спрашивать.

Comment: @AK, спасибо за прояснение, все доходчиво и понятно

Comment: @AK Отлично пояснили

Comment: @AK чего не ответом? )